# Document Root PHP

Tags: php, html, root

Just to confirm, is using:

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
```

the same as using: /

in HTML.

Eg. If current document is:

```
folder/folder/folder/index.php
```

I could use (in HTML) to start at the roort:

```
/somedoc.html
```

and to do the same in PHP I would have to use:

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/somedoc.html";
```

Is that correct? Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/hello.html'; ?>">go with php</a>
    <br />
<a href="/hello.html">go to with html</a>
```

Try this yourself and find that they are not exactly the same.

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` renders an actual file path (on my computer running as it's own server, `C:/wamp/www/`

HTML's `/` renders the root of the server url, in my case, `localhost/`

But `C:/wamp/www/hello.html` and `localhost/hello.html` are in fact the same file

Comment: if you want to use it say for include(), its a different issue than for a hyper-link above.

Comment: No reason to post my answer since this one is what I was going to say.

Comment: What's different with includes?

Comment: You'll need a `/` between `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and `hello.html`

Comment: file path and url are not the same thing

Answer (score 5):

Just `/` refers to the root of your website from the public html folder. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` refers to the local path to the folder on the server that contains your website.

For example, I have EasyPHP setup on a machine...

`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` gives me `file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/EasyPHP-5.3.9/www` but any file I link to with just `/` will be relative to my `www` folder.

If you want to give the absolute path to a file on your server (from the server's root) you can use `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. if you want to give the absolute path to a file from your website's root, use just `/`.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` contains the *server side path* which correlates to the *client side URL path* `/`. But, **No** they are not interchangeable.

They are not interchangeable because, for example, the server side path should never be sent to the client (HTML) side. The value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is not `/`; it is the server's local *file path* to what the server shows the client at `/`. So, the value of `${$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/images/thumbnail.png"` may be the string `/var/www/html/images/thumbnail.png` on a server where it's local file at that path can be reached from the client side at the url `http://example.com/images/thumbnail.png`

note: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` does not include a trailing `/`

Comment: "on the server side $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is equivalent to / on the client side." this is ambiguous at best and potentially misleading. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should never be used as a reference address in HTML. Always simply use HTML `/` .

Comment: I have moved the clarification statement to be part of the initial statement, and cleaned up the result, in an attempt to mitigate the ambiguity you (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536236/martin) saw.

Answer (score -4):

The Easiest way to do it is to have good site structure and write it as a constant.

```
DEFINE("BACK_ROOT","/var/www/");
```

Comment: i know its old but i stumbled upon this, why would you make more constants if you already have a php defined server constant doing this, waste of code, cpu and memory

Comment: The idea is, no matter how far deep (folder-wise) you are in includes, this makes it so you'll never have to write code relative to the script, other than the code used to define the root.

I use this to combat the Jerry-rigging method used by many programmers today.

Comment: yes but that way you script becomes depended on the system or on the location, which it should never be, apps should be portable