# Root command/code not working after PHP upgrade from 5.2 to 5.5

Tags: php, root, document

After an PHP upgrade from 5.2 to 5.5 (or newer) a friend's web site is not working anymore, regarding the host identifier ($DOCUMENT_ROOT).

He is using this code:

```
<?php
require("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/menulinks.inc.php");    
$status = $menu["home"]["id"];
require("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/header.inc.php");
?>
<div id="main">
<img src="images/miristart.jpg" alt="Startbild" style="margin-top 2%;"/>    
</div>
<?php 
require("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/footer.inc.php");
?>
```

And that is the error code:

```
Warning: require(/menulinks.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/htdocs/v137122/sedcard.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/menulinks.inc.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:..') in /www/htdocs/v137122/sedcard.php on line 2
```

So, do I have to use another command instead of $DOCUMENT_ROOT? Which one then? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You could check out the answers to this similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927968/document-root-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Document Root PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927968/document-root-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First  $DOCUMENT_ROOT is a variable.

During the update the PHP option `register_globals` was set to `off`. You can still access the document root through the `$_SERVER` array. This will look like `$_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: I changed require("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/menulinks.inc.php"); to require("$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/menulinks.inc.php");, but that did not work at all.

Comment: Your code `"$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/menulinks.inc.php"` will resolve to `"Array['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/menulinks.inc.php"`You need to add curly braces: `"{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/menulinks.inc.php"`

Comment: {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']} did the job, thank you very much. :)