# How can I use one navigation file

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

I am receiving an

> "Object not found!
>   The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster."

which is pretty obverse to me. problem is when I use  on all the page where I need the navigation bar to work on. some of my links ty to go to http://localhost/xenxarragroup/site_03/site_03/gallary/index.php
which should really be going to
http://localhost/xenxarragroup/site_03/gallary/index.php.
I get this problem say when i click
from home  say my Gallery page then to Design room I get "Object not found!"part which leadsa me back to this
http://localhost/xenxarragroup/site_03/site_03/gallary/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>XarraLures - Home</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="im/favicon.ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav.css" />
</head>

<body>
<!--class="pressed"-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="header" id="top">
   <div class="menuBar" id="menuBar">
        <!--<input type="checkbox" id="css3menu-switcher" class="c3m-switch-input">-->
        <ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
            <li class="topfirst"><a href="../index.php" title="Home" 
 target="_parent" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">Home</a></li>
            <li class="topmenu"><a href="../site_03/gallary/index.php" title="Show Room" target="_parent" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">Show 
 Room</a></li>
            <li class="topmenu"><a href="../site_03/Design/index.php" title="Design Room" target="_parent" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">Design Room</a></li>
            <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" target="_parent" 
 style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">Shop</a></li>
 <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" target="_parent" 
 style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">Enquires</a></li>
            <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" target="_parent" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">Comments</a></li>
            <li class="toplast"><a href="#" target="_parent" style="height:18px;line-height:18px;">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>s
    </div>
 </DIV>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

the only thing I tried is to change the allocations of the directory to which it it point to

Comment: Use absolute path (from `/`) instead of relative ones (`../`)

Comment: Use `href="/` instead of `href="../`. (`href="/` will point to the topmost directory)

Comment: @Cid and kerbholz Then what happens when the site moves and the path from the new servers root is different

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's indeed boring to edit the path when it's moved, one solution could be to use some kind of settings file that will store the path from `/` to the real root folder of that site. Then in php, re-build that path. I personnaly prefer using a framework with a routing system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927968/document-root-php

Comment: @RiggsFolly yep, that. or `__DIR__` to get a path relative to that navigation file

Comment: @RiggsFolly Oh well, in fact no, this won't work.